# Is it ethical for students to consume Adderall during university courses, if they don't have ADHD?

Tags: ethics, drugs

Assume a student in the United States who has access to Adderall despite not suffering from ADHD. Would it be ethical for them to take the drug during their studies?

Assume that the school is within the United States. When answering only the academic side of things should be taken into account – I am fully aware that taking a drug without a proper prescription is illegal.

Comment: What do you mean "academic side of things"? i.e. can you be expelled?

Comment: @MichaelC. I'm asking what actions could the university take against such a student and if it's ethical to consume the drug in the first place.

Comment: Is it ethical to study? Is it ethical to read a different textbook? Is it ethical to just be smarter than somebody else? Is it ethical to drink coffee when others don't or won't? Is it ethical to drink a beer while doing a problem set? Many people ask about 'ethics' here without really thinking through if that is even the right thing to think about. What, really, are you concerned about?

Comment: @JonCuster There is a lot of talk in academia about how students 'abuse' drugs to get ahead. I'm trying to understand if it's an actual concern in academia or if it's something implicitly approved/ignored.

Comment: But is that an ethics issue or a legal issue?

Comment: @JonCuster ethics. The legal situation is crystal clear.

Comment: And the ethical situation is as well - students do any number of things that may or may not give them an advantage or make them smarter. If coffee is OK ethically, Adderall is OK ethically.

Comment: @JonCuster ok, thank you. Feel free to add that as answer.

Comment: @JonathanReez - But is it ethical to break the law? // For certain ADHD cases, I call Adderal "stimulant medication."  In other cases, I call it "speed."

Comment: @aparente001 in this case yes, because it's a victimless crime. I'd argue taking drugs is ethical regardless of the legal standing. However academics are a different ethics beast.

Comment: @JonathanReez - I am not an ethicist. Perhaps this is the wrong place for these fine distinctions. It would be easier to address your question if you explained where this question is coming from. // Do you consider suicide ethical, in general?  (I'm not talking about special situations, such as a person with an incurable disease and unbearable pain, etc.)

Comment: @aparente001 suicide is ethical as well. Cheating on a test is not. Taking doping during a sports competition is not. Bribing the professor to get good grades is not.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm trying to understand the current attitude towards such drugs in Academia - it seems that people have a problem with it, but I don't understand what the problem is exactly.

Comment: @JonathanReez - *I don't understand what the problem is exactly.*  Well, I am not a medical expert.  This might be a good question for Health Beta, and/or for your medical provider.  My general impression is that self-prescribing stimulants and certain other medications brings certain physical and mental health risks. // I feel differently about suicide than you do.  But I'm probably not the most objective person for that topic (I have lost a close relative to suicide).  And as I said, I have not made a careful study of ethics.

Comment: Just throwing this out there-- if regularly consuming adderall helps you enough that you feel compelled to use it in the long term, how sure are you that you don't have ADHD?

Comment: The question could be extended generally to whether other illegal acts are necessarily unethical from an academic perspective. For example, writing a paper on a stolen computer (when your computer is significantly slower or more difficult to use), parking illegally to make it to lectures or exams on time, or studying while unlawfully in the country.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I think the theory is that the medication increases one's ability to tolerate boredom, irrespective of whether one is feeling boredom due to having ADHD or due to being faced with an objectively boring task (the unspoken assumption being that exam revision is an objectively boring task).  I have no idea whether there's any evidence for that theory, nor indeed whether "feeling boredom" is an accurate characterisation of the symptoms of ADHD.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Academia is not a competition, neither is school. It's about education and knowledge. Neither comes and goes with a few pills.

Applying the anti-doping rules from sports is therefore nonsense. What applies are the common workplace anti-drug rules.

Comment: So it's okay if the student is not 'high' during classes?

Comment: Of course it's not okay. It's probably reason enough to kick him out, but *not reason' to have him fail that class. Total misapplication.

Comment: But if anti-doping rules don't apply and you're not 'high' on school property, what makes it 'not okay'?

Comment: If you keep the drug off campus (also from your bloodsteam), nothing, except that you are possibly commiting a criminal offence by buying, possessing and handling it. My faculty refuses to graduate anyone with a recent criminal record. Saveguarding their reputation etc. Of course if you only take the stuff in your holidays, there is little point in your original question.

Comment: AFAIK amphetamines have a relatively short half life so you could go to classes each morning, get back home, take the pills, and come back clean the next morning. Assuming you don't get caught by police, is it okay to tell your professor you're taking a 'study aid'?

Comment: @JonathanReez Herbal supplements are "study aids". Adderall is a prescription psychoactive drug. Calling it a study aid is essentially not telling in the first place.

Comment: @David ok, you come to your professor and say 'I'm taking Adderall for your class, in the privacy of my home'. Would that be cause for suspension?

Comment: Look, we're  not lawyers here. You'll look like an idiot, you will probably get in trouble with your school (US universities have all kinds of regulations for students private live), but your prof has imo no legitimate reason to have you fail the class. P.S. You taking drugs is your private decision, imo, Forcing your prof to become involved is totally inappropriate.

Comment: @JonathanReez It really depends on your school and your local laws. For example, I'm a prof in the US, which means that under Title IX law I am legally required to report sexual harassment. Failure to do so could technically cause my entire university to lose federal funding. I'm not aware of any similar laws for drug offenses, but your school may have a policy in place that requires reporting student drug offenses. At a minimum, as Karl has said, your professors probably isn't going to think highly of it.

Comment: @JonathanReez It's also very important to note that even if a professor has no duty to report drug behavior, there's absolutely nothing stopping them from reporting it because they feel they need to.

Comment: @JonathanReez As others have already said, check your university policy as to what penalties there are for drug use. A 10-second google search turns up at least one college that specifically states that it can suspend, expel, and report you to the police for drug use on campus: https://www.texarkanacollege.edu/catalog/article/alcohol-drug-use-policy/

Comment: @David but that policy is only related to college grounds. They say nothing about taking drugs off-site. It also doesn't seem to be an ethics issue.

Answer (score 7):

It is illegal for anyone to take prescription medication not prescribed directly to them by an authorized medical professional. Universities in the US are not safe guarded from federal, state, and local laws. So if your school found out that you are abusing drugs, they can expel you. You will most likely go through a hearing process where you are offered due diligence.

If you are looking for the policy at a specific school, just visit the school's website and search for their Alcohol and Drug Policy.

Comment: Yes, but what about the Academic side? Question slightly updated.

Comment: @JonathanReez I think your academic concern is a little misplaced. People wind up in jail for buying and selling prescription drugs illegally. A criminal record is going to affect your life more than violations of school policy, and that's the risk you take when you're engaging in illegal activity.

Comment: @David I don't have access to Adderall, nor do I need any. I'm simply interested if taking the drug is 'allowed', 'frowned upon' or 'completely unacceptable'. E.g. can you proudly talk about your Adderall intake with your professor?

Comment: @JonathanReez Your professors are going to have wildly different reactions. I have met people who would not care. I have met people who would probably consider it academic dishonesty and cheating. I don't know what I would say if a student told me this, I've never been in that situation.

Comment: Your prof will regard you as a fool, never hire you, and probably tell the officials that you are taking drugs on campus. But regarding you as a "cheater" for it is seems to be on the intellectual and moral level of giving the convicted thief a random speeding ticket, imo. ymmv

Comment: @David Not necessarily. It is easier to lvie a life of the mind in prison than it is working some menial jobs.

Comment: @Karl but if you're not taking the drug on campus it's okay? And why is Adderall worse than coffee, alcohol or cigarettes?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was about ethics, not law. *So if your school found out that you are abusing drugs, they can expel you.* This is absurd, unless we're talking about Bob Jones University or something. A school in the US is not going to expel a student for using adderall without a prescription.

Comment: @BenCrowell It is not absurd. Per Harvard College: "When cases involving drugs and alcohol come to the attention of the College, the College may take disciplinary action against a student, including requirement to withdraw." A number of other colleges have the similar language.

Answer (score 5):

Whether it's ethical or not depends on your own system of ethics. But, a few things that come to mind. Full disclosure: I've never used these kinds of drugs and I'm not a medical doctor.

1) Just like steroids are considered unfair sportsmanship, cognition drugs will be viewed as unfair in academics by people who are concerned about fairness.

2) Taking drugs to artificially enhance your performance doesn't help you in the long run. Do you really want to take drugs your entire life to maintain an artificial level of performance? Things like better study skills, time management, and prioritization will enhance your performance more effectively and will help you through your whole life.

3) Are you going to feel OK with yourself knowing that you didn't live your life on your own terms? Later in life you're never really going to know whether you could have met your challenges on your own.

4) [The people who don't want you to use adderall](http://americanaddictioncenters.org/adderall/long-term-effects/) will tell you that there are a range of serious health consequences for abusing prescription drugs, including long-term cardiovascular, neurological, and mental issues. Sacrificing your health for success is viewed as unethical by some systems of reason.

5) Finally, these drugs are referred to as "cognition-enhancers", but [the science is still out](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3489818/#__sec7title) on whether or not they really assist in anything beyond rote memorization in people without ADHD. Other researchers have suggested that drug use might lead to deficiencies like decreased creativity.

Comment: Regarding 2): Didn't Paul Erdős consume amphetamines throughout his whole career?

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't know, but don't ask for ethical principles and then suggest that something should be OK just because someone else successful did it. The world is full of very successful but unethical people.

Comment: Ok, but otherwise only 1) tries to answer the real question. Do any university guidelines mention stimulants? Can you get expelled for taking them?

Comment: @JonathanReez If it is against your university policy then you absolutely can be expelled for it. Additionally, many university policies generally prohibit illegal actions while on campus without specifically mentioning prescription drug abuse.

Comment: @JonathanReez, Erdős began using amphetamines in 1971, 37 years after receiving his PhD.

Answer (score 1):

I would point out that a major concern in academics is the *sustainability* of the practice.

I assume you are talking about undergraduate, but most academics are PhDs. This means (in my experience) we have seen numerous students, classmates, peers, and colleagues drop out of school or the industry, hurt themselves physically or mentally, or (very rarely) hurt others.  We are always concerned about such things, they make us sad.

Use of Dextroamphetamine or other ADHD medications is not problem free - use of drugs that have side effects such as heart problems, paranoia, mood swings, and a strong tendency towards chemical dependence are not seen as sustainable - particularly for those who do not even have the disorder. Nor are the benefits clear cut (as others have pointed out). Students report themselves as 'feeling' like have learned more, but in actuality, it is not clear they are actually learning more.

As such, these people are engaging in a dangerous practice with unclear benefits. I see that the comparison to performance enhancing drugs are good for reasons other than you anticipated. It is not that such actions are "unsportsmanlike" which is nebulous in a learning environment. Rather, the costs are too great and the benefits so unclear that individuals undertaking such a risk is undesirable. Students hoping such substances work for them (when they don't even have the disorder) are too likely to self-destruct and this is not a great learning environment for those students or their peers.

Comment: Self harm is usually viewed as unethical.